# Как скопировать dll библиотеки к исполняемому файлу?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

В VisualStudio15 Нужно скопировать dll библиотеки к исполняемому файлу во время сборки. Пост билд для этого не подходит. В VS8 был Suport File Copy в настройках проекта и в директории проекта лежал файл `FILE_COPY_DLL.rule` с таким содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VisualStudioToolFile
    Name="Support file copy"
    Version="8,00"
    >
    <Rules>
        <CustomBuildRule
            Name="Support file copy"
            CommandLine="xcopy /Q /Y &quot;$(InputPath)&quot;         &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;"
            Outputs="$(TargetDir)$(InputFileName)"
            FileExtensions="*.dll;*.ini"
            >
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </CustomBuildRule>
    </Rules>
</VisualStudioToolFile>
```

и в файле проекта были такие строки:

```
<ToolFiles>
    <ToolFile
        RelativePath=".\FILE-COPY-DLL.rule"
    />
</ToolFiles>
```

Как это можно сделать в VisualStudio 15?

Comment: Свойство файла -> Copy to output directory -> Copy always

Answer (score -1):

Если добавляете как `Reference`, находите в списке и `CopyLocal = True`.